# Run Server 2012 Refresh from a command line?

Tags: windows-server-2012

Much as the subject says, anyone know how to do a System Refresh on Server 2012 from the command line?

This is a 'Minimal Server Interface' mode Server 2012 install so no full GUI.

Have tried running a Refresh boot CD but this fails at 1% with:

```
There was a problem refreshing your PC.  No changes were made.
```

Comment: Is that even possible?

Comment: Well the option is there when the recovery environment is run from a boot DVD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have just discovered that despite being present the 'Refresh your PC' option is not designed to work with Server 2012.

There is a 'Reset your PC' option but question is does this work on Server 2012 or is it a dummy like Refresh your PC?

Edit:
Microsoft have now confirmed that Refresh your PC is not intended to work on Server 2012, although quite why the option is present if it is not intended to be used is baffling.

Edit2:
Answer is to be found in other thread here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/496417/reinstall-server-2012

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just rebuild your server? Apart from as an "Emergency Get Out" I'd never trust restore modes etc on a Server Operating System.

Comment: Because the license key will not allow a fresh install again hence the reason for trying to find a way to reinstall without loosing the activation key.

Comment: @NickC The Server 2012 key? It stands a high chance that any kind of repair will force reactivation anyway. Why do you think yours won't allow an install?

Comment: Last time I had to do a telephone activation it was a _very_ long and tedious operation made worse by the fact that I could hardly understand the foreign accent of the Microsoft Product Activation team.

Comment: @NickC So you're seriously going to compromise the stability of your server because you want to avoid a slightly irritating phone call. You could have rebuilt and reactivated your server by now, anyway.